# Binary Tree get parent node not working

Tags: segmentation-fault, binary-tree

I am making my delete function so first i'm trying to find the parent node but i keep getting a seg fault. The find parent works when a parent has 2 children but when it has one child it crashes. I keep trying to switch things around but I can't figure it out can someone help me please.

```
Node* BST::getParentNode(int value){

    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp = _root;

    while (temp != NULL){

        Node* left = temp->getLeft();

        Node* right = temp->getRight();

        if (left->getData() == value)
            return temp;
        if (right->getData() == value)
            return temp;

        if (right->getData() > value){
            temp = temp->getRight();
        }
        else{
            temp = temp->getLeft();
        }

    }

    Node* empty = new Node;
    empty = NULL;
    return empty;
}
```

Comment: You have several issues here. First, what about the data in the current node - should you not compare to that first? Then, allocating a new node and then overwriting that variable with something else is going to be unrewarding and also leak memory, like you do both with `temp` and `empty`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking your left and right pointers aren't null before accessing them.  See below for comments

```
Node* BST::getParentNode(int value){

//  Node* temp = new Node; // This line isn't needed...
    Node* temp = _root;

    while (temp != NULL){

        Node* left = temp->getLeft();

        Node* right = temp->getRight();

        if(NULL != left) {    // You are missing this check.  I'm assuming this can happen
                              // because it's part of your exit condition from the while loop
            if (left->getData() == value)
                return temp;
        }
        if(NULL != right) {  // You are also missing this check. You can't call function on
                             // null pointers...
            if (right->getData() == value)
                return temp;
        }

        if (right->getData() > value){
            temp = temp->getRight();
        }
        else{
            temp = temp->getLeft();
        }

    }

    // It's unclear what you're trying to do on the next three lines
    // you create an object with new, then throw the memory away by assigning the
    // pointer to NULL      
    Node* empty = new Node;
    empty = NULL;
    return empty;  // With the code as is, you might as well return NULL;
                   // which would also get rid of the memory leak...
}
```